# Customize kendo panelbar item header

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2, kendo-panelbar

I have the following panelbar:

```
     <kendo-panelbar *ngIf="mainMenu" 
        [expandMode]="expandMode">
        <kendo-panelbar-item [title]="menuItem.title" *ngFor="let menuItem of mainMenu" iconClass="fa fa-lg {{menuItem.faIcon}}"
          [routerLink]="menuItem.link" routerLinkActive="active">
            <kendo-panelbar-item [title]="menuItemSub.title" *ngFor="let menuItemSub of menuItem.sub" 
            [routerLink]="menuItemSub.link" routerLinkActive="active">
            </kendo-panelbar-item>
        </kendo-panelbar-item>
      </kendo-panelbar>
```

An example of the generated item is like this:

```
    <kendo-panelbar-item routerlinkactive="active" tabindex="0" ng-reflect-router-link="/dashboard-edge" 
ng-reflect-router-link-active="active" ng-reflect-title="Dashboard Edge" 
ng-reflect-icon-class="fa fa-lg fa-window-maximize" role="treeitem" 
class="k-item k-state-default " id="k-panelbar-item-default-1" aria-selected="false">
    <span class="k-link k-header">
        <!--bindings={"ng-reflect-ng-if": "fa fa-lg fa-window-maximize"}-->
        <span class="k-icon fa fa-lg fa-window-maximize" ng-reflect-klass="k-icon" 
        ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]">
        </span>
        <!--bindings={"ng-reflect-ng-if": ""}-->
        Dashboard Edge
        <!--bindings={}-->
        <!--bindings={"ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"}-->
    </span>
<!--bindings={"ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"}-->
</kendo-panelbar-item>
```

How can I customize the content of the item (with HTML) so that I can get more control of how the information is displayed? For instance, I would like to have the title wrapped in a `<span>` tag with some specific class.

I'm able to customize the content using templates, but not the header itself.

Comment: do you have any panelbar dropdowns? or are they just buttons?

Comment: @mast3rd3mon Some of the items have sub items, if that is what you're asking...

Comment: yeah it is, so is it every top level button/item group that you want to customise?

Comment: @mast3rd3mon For now yes. But I suppose if I want to customize the child items, the approach will be similar.

Comment: what are you wanting it to look like?

Comment: I want to wrap the title in a `span`. My problem is to know how can I render HTML in the header.

Comment: i dont think that you can, you cant add html to the text bind property and any html put in the panelbar header tag will be treated as html in the panel bar. WHy not just apply styles and css classes to the panelbar?

Comment: @mast3rd3mon Take a look at my answer ;)

Comment: looking at the plunkr, i dont see how that is any different from what you normally get?

Comment: @mast3rd3mon did you check the app/app.component.ts file?

Comment: yeah, just looks like extra code to do the same thing?

Comment: @mast3rd3mon No. That way you can wrap the title in a span, add a css class, etc. Which was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Telerik support helped me with this.

Basically, you only need to:

- Pass null to `[title]` binding
- And create the `ng-template` with the `kendoPanelBarItemTitle` directive

Here is an example:

```
<kendo-panelbar *ngIf="mainMenu" 
        [expandMode]="expandMode">
        <kendo-panelbar-item [title]="null" *ngFor="let menuItem of mainMenu" iconClass="fa fa-lg {{menuItem.faIcon}}"
          [routerLink]="menuItem.link" routerLinkActive="active" [attr.name]="menuItem.name">
            <ng-template kendoPanelBarItemTitle>
                <span class="item-title">{{menuItem.title}}</span>
            </ng-template>
            <kendo-panelbar-item [title]="null" *ngFor="let menuItemSub of menuItem.sub" 
            [routerLink]="menuItemSub.link" routerLinkActive="active" [attr.name]="menuItemSub.name">
            <ng-template kendoPanelBarItemTitle>
                <span class="sub item-title">{{menuItemSub.title}}</span>
            </ng-template>
            </kendo-panelbar-item>
        </kendo-panelbar-item>
      </kendo-panelbar>
```

Example provided by Telerik guys: [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/LqKjLo9GIrpaKJzqemfn?p=preview)